# how to concatenate number values with the URL in crystal report formula

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I need to add fixed values to the URL how to add the values to the URL this is the formula code :

```
stringvar replaceid := Replace(totext({GET_ALLORDER_RESULT_PRINT_CASH;1.order number}),",",""); 
stringvar replaceids := Replace(replaceid,".00",""); 

numberVar testid = 6438;
numberVar deptid = 11;
numberVar culture = 2;

stringVar barcodeInput:=  "http://www.store.com/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?order_id="&""&replaceids;
```

How to add testid , deptid and culture at the end of URL barcodeInput in crystal report formula

I need to call and open URL with these variables , I need your help please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula has multiple issues:

1. You seem to try to format the number with `Replace`. This can be done with `ToText`, if used correctly.
   (Just highlight `ToText` in formula editor and press <kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. `=` does not assign a value to the `numberVar` variables. Use `:=` for assignment.
3. The variable `barcodeInput` is not required

The following should work:

```
stringVar orderid := ToText({GET_ALLORDER_RESULT_PRINT_CASH;1.order number},0,"");  

numberVar testid := 6438;
numberVar deptid := 11;
numberVar culture := 2;

"http://www.store.com/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?" &
"order_id=" & orderid &
"&testid=" & ToText(testid,0,"") &
"&deptid=" & ToText(deptid,0,"") &
"&culture=" & ToText(culture,0,"");
```